# Add key-value pair to a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array: `user = {"name" => "Tom", "address" => "Spain"}`

I want to add to this a new attribute:  `user << {"age" => 26}`

I get this error: `undefined method '<<' for {"name"=>"Tom", "address"=>"Spain"}:Hash`

How should I add a new value for this element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add key value pair this way

```
user["age"] = 26 # => {"name"=>"Tom", "address"=>"Spain", "age"=>26}
```

or you can use `merge`

```
user.merge("age" => 26) # => {"name"=>"Tom", "address"=>"Spain", "age"=>26}
```

Comment: Beat me by 17 secs :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Ruby hashes aren't ordered, appending to them with << doesn't make sense.

However, you can use

```
user["age"] = 26
```

to the same effect.